# Не убивается процесс из определённой папки

Tags: c#

Как решить проблему убийства процесса  запущенного из определённой папки ?

Программа откомпилирована в `AnyCpu`

Метод для убивания:

```
public static void KillProcessByPartOfPath(string partOfPath)
{
   try
   {
     foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
     {
       try
       {
        if (process.MainModule.FileName.IndexOf(partOfPath, 
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
        {
          try
          {
            process.Kill();
          }
          catch (Exception) { break; }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception) { }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Пишет:

> Отказано в доступе

Comment: От имени Администратора пробовали запускать?

Comment: @Sergey_73, Естественно!  Пробовал перекомпилировать под разные архитектуры x64, x86 ни как не хочет получать доступ, `SeDebugPrivilege` включён